# How do I spawn a random object after every so many other objects spawn?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I am creating a Bullet Hell Shooter/Asteroids and I got the random asteroids spawning now, however I want to know how to spawn a random enemy ship after every 5-10 asteroids, to make the game more detailed.

I realised I will need a counter using snippets as well as an 'if statement' however I don't know how to do this? Please help if you can.

```
var background = new Background;

background.x = 200;
background.y = 200;

addChild(background);

var ship = new Ship

ship.x = 125;
ship.y = 350;

addChild(ship);

var rocks = new Array(); // Create 10 rocks for  
{ 
    var rock = new Rock(); 
    rock.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth; 
    rock.y = 0; rocks.push( rock ); 
    addChild(rock);
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,stepDown);

function stepDown(event:Event)
{
   // step down each rock
   for ( var i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
   {
      rocks[i].y += 5;
       // Check if rocks fall from stage than set it on new position
      if ( stage.stageHeight < rocks[i].y )
      {
         rocks[i].y = 0;
         rocks[i].x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth
      }
   }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_PressKeyToMove);

function fl_PressKeyToMove(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            ship.x -= 15;
            if (ship.hitTestObject(Wall2))
            {
                ship.x +=15 ;
            }
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            ship.x += 15;
            if (ship.hitTestObject(Wall1))
            {
                ship.x -=15 ;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

ship.gotoAndStop("normal");

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,detectCollision);
function detectCollision(event:Event)
{
     if(ship.hitTestObject(rock))
     {
         ship.gotoAndPlay("boom");
         ship.stop();
         stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_PressKeyToMove);
     }
}

addChild(enemy);
```

Comment: You could keep a counter which you update every time. when counter % 11 == 0 , spawn ship instead of asteroid?

Comment: @Joeblade Thanks for the reply but do you know how I would type the code, as I am really bad at the coding?

Comment: I've tried to search for a counter but all am getting is end game counter score and not the timer for the enemy ship to spawn, do you know how to fix this by any chance?

Comment: I was waiting to see if anyone else wanted to answer your question. I'll write one now. However if you are having trouble coding a simple counter then I have to ask, what are you doing writing a game? :) You might need to start with simpler exercises first

Comment: @Joeblade well I'm taking Games Design in college and one of my main tasks are to create an app, I've been doing this for over a month now and I found that I haven't been able to make any progress unless I ask. I have made a lot of progress, but know I need these extra features as I want a better grade.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code seems to be hardcoded to deal with 10 asteroids. I

```
function stepDown(event:Event) {
   // step down each rock
   for ( var i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
```

You would have to change this to:

```
function stepDown(event:Event) {
   // step down each rock
   for ( var i = 0; i < rocks.length; ++i )
```

During your stepDown you probably also need to loop over all enemy ships so add to this method:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < enemyShips.length; ++i)
```

As you'll want to update the position of enemy ships as well

In the code you posted I do not see the method that creates new rocks (I see a { } block that might be used for it though.

to do a next spawn you would need methods to call.
During your gameloop, when you decide it is time for a new spawn (rock or ship) call spawn() as listed below

```
var otherMobs = new Array();
var counter = 0;
function spawn() {
    counter++;
    if (counter % 10 == 0) {
        spawnShip();
    } else {
        spawnRock();
    }
}

function spawnShip() {
    var enemyShip = new EnemyShip(); 
    enemyShip.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth; 
    enemyShip.y = 0; 
    otherMobs.push( enemyShip ); 
    addChild(enemyShip);    
}

function spawnRock() {
    var rock = new Rock();
    rock =.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth; 
    rock =.y = 0; 
    rocks.push( rock = ); 
    addChild(rock =);    
}
```